# install MSMQ on windows XP uE

Tags: windows, msmq

I am running windows XP uE SP3 and I need to install MSMQ in order to install wincc (a Siemens automation software) the problem is that this UE version doesn't let me add/remove windows components because of what it is -an unattended edition. 
so my question is.. is there any other way to install msmq? I mean, some executable installer or something like that
any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: is that Windows XP Embedded or something else?